# How to add side effects while running an Animated animation sequence?

Tags: animation, react-native

Im trying to build a countdown timer, and for each count i want play a sound. The animation works fine but i want to know if i can play the sound when running an animation in a sequence.

**CODE:**

```
Animated.sequence([

            Animated.timing(this.state.moveY3,  {
                toValue: 50,
                duration: 1000,
                useNativeDrive: true,
                easing: Easing.spring
            }),  // play sound

            Animated.timing(this.state.moveY3,  {
                toValue: 100,
                duration: 100,
                useNativeDrive: true,
            }),

            Animated.timing(this.state.moveY2,  {
                toValue: 50,
                duration: 1000,
                useNativeDrive: true,
                easing: Easing.spring
            }), //play sound

            Animated.timing(this.state.moveY2,  {
                toValue: 100,
                duration: 500,
                useNativeDrive: true,
            }),

            Animated.timing(this.state.moveY1,  {
                toValue: 50,
                duration: 1000,
                useNativeDrive: true,
                easing: Easing.spring
            }), // play sound

            Animated.timing(this.state.moveY1,  {
                toValue: 100,
                duration: 500,
                useNativeDrive: true,
            }),


]).start()
```

Note: I know how to play sound, Im using the react-native-sound package, Im just confused as to how to the play the sound at each count.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Into the `start()` method of each Animation [a callback can be added which is executed upon completion of the animation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/animated.html#working-with-animations).
So instead of writing all your animation in a `sequence` you could break it up into smaller parts, like so:

```
// Run animation

animation1.start(() => {
    playSound1();
    Animated.sequence([
        animation2,
        animation3,
    ]).start(() => {
        playSound2();
        Animated.sequence([
            animation4,
            animation5,
        ]).start(() => {
            playSound3();
            animation6.start();
        })
    })
});

// Move animations into variables so that the execution of the animation is more readable

const animation1 = Animated.timing(this.state.moveY3,  {
    toValue: 50,
    duration: 1000,
    useNativeDrive: true,
    easing: Easing.spring
});

const animation2 = Animated.timing(this.state.moveY3,  {
    toValue: 100,
    duration: 100,
    useNativeDrive: true,
}),

const animation3 = Animated.timing(this.state.moveY2,  {
    toValue: 50,
    duration: 1000,
    useNativeDrive: true,
    easing: Easing.spring
}),

...
```

By moving some stuff of the first bit into other functions you could reduce the nesting a bit and make it more readable.. but it should work like that..

Comment: Excellent answer